# Swipe Gestures not working on Android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm using swipe gestures from [glepur: react-native-swipe-gestures](https://github.com/glepur/react-native-swipe-gestures)

It works just fine on iOS but I'm having issues with Android. It work on every try on iOS, but Android works every now and then. Here's how I'm using it:

```
import GestureRecognizer, { swipeDirections } from 'react-native-swipe-gestures';

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      gestureName: 'none',
    };

this.onSwipe = this.onSwipe.bind(this);
this.onLeftSwipe = this.onLeftSwipe.bind(this);
this.onRightSwipe = this.onRightSwipe.bind(this);
}

onSwipe(gestureName, gestureState) {
    const { SWIPE_LEFT, SWIPE_RIGHT } = swipeDirections;
    switch (gestureName) {
      case SWIPE_LEFT:
        this.swipeLeftFn();
        break;
      case SWIPE_RIGHT:
        this.swipeRightFn();
        break;
      default:
    }
  }
}

render() {
    const config = {
      velocityThreshold: 0.3,
      directionalOffsetThreshold: 80,
    };

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <GestureRecognizer
          onSwipe={(direction, state) => this.onSwipe(direction, state)}
          config={config}
        >
        <View />
        </GestureRecognizer>
      </View>
    )
  }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

edit: binding functions

Comment: What's the symptom?

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca the `swipeLeftFn` & `swipeRightFn` functions don't fire when swiping left to right or right to left.

Comment: is onSwipe fired? In the way you have put the code I would say the problem is that those functions are not binded.

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca after `this.state` I binded the fns with 
    `this.onSwipe = this.onSwipe.bind(this);
    this.swipeLeftFn = this.swipeLeftFn.bind(this);
    this.swipeRightFn = this.swipeRightFn.bind(this);`

functions are still not being fired

Comment: Ok, can you add your current code please? It is hard otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: @FacundoLaRocca done

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162364/discussion-between-dres-and-facundo-la-rocca).

Answer (score 2):

Fixed it!

Swipe gestures seemed to work randomly but it was actually only working on the limited space of the components that were wrapped by the `<GestureRecognizer>`

So I removed the initial `<View>` and replaced it with the `<GestureRecognizer>`. It looks like this:

```
return (
    <GestureRecognizer
      onSwipe={(direction, state) => this.onSwipe(direction, state)}
      config={config}
      style={styles.container}
    >
      <View />
    </GestureRecognizer>
  )
```

Comment: how were you testing this, on device or on simulator? I'm trying to do the same thing and implemented code the same way you did, however I didn't get it to work. I wrapped my View in the gesture handler and there seemed to be no Swipe detection. Testing on iOS simulator - wondering if it has to be done on a device?

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me, but wasn't able to resolve for react-native-swipe-gestures

I've found simpler solution, that to use this lib - works perfect:

```
<View
      onTouchStart={e=> this.touchY = e.nativeEvent.pageY}
      onTouchEnd={e => {
        if (this.touchY - e.nativeEvent.pageY > 20)
          console.log('Swiped up')
      }}
      style={{height: 300, backgroundColor: '#ccc'}}
    />
```